# Why is my method querying by service_code instead of id?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am developing an API where I have services and sales which is a many to many relationship. Therefore I created a join table names saleservices which contains the `sale_id` and the `service_id`.

This are my models

Service.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Service = sequelize.define('Service', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    service_code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    service_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(20,2),
        allowNull: false,
    },
});

module.exports = Service;
```

Sale.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Sale = sequelize.define('Sale', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    employee_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'employees',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'customers',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    
});

module.exports = Sale;
```

And this is my SaleService.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const SaleService = sequelize.define('SaleService', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    sale_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'sales', 
            key: 'id'
        },
    },
    service_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'services',
            key: 'id'
        },
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'SaleService', 
    timestamps: false, 
});

module.exports = SaleService;
```

For some reason in my sales controller when I want to create a sale and I pass a list of services, instead of querying by the id which is the primary key, it queries by the service_code which is undefined and I get the error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Services' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'hackacode2.0'   
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `Services`
Error: WHERE parameter "service_code" has invalid "undefined" value
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (C:\Users\Mateo\Desktop\projects\hackacode2.0-backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1743:13)
```

This is my method:

```
const Sale = require('../models/Sale.model');
const Service = require('../models/Service.model');
const SaleService = require('../models/SaleService.model');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');
const asyncHandler = require('../middleware/async');

//@route   POST /api/v1/sales
//@desc    Create Sale
//@access  Private

exports.createSale = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { services, customer_id, employee_id } = req.body;

    const sale = await Sale.create({ employee_id, customer_id });

    const saleServices = await Promise.all(services.map(async (serviceData) => {
        const { id } = serviceData;
        console.log('id', id)
        const service = await Service.findByPk(id, { attributes: ['id'] });
        if (!service) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Service with id: ${id} not found`, 404));
        }

        return SaleService.create({ 
            sale_id: sale.id, 
            service_id: id, 
        });
    }));

    res.status(201).json({ sale, saleServices });
});
```

So I create a sale where I pass `employee_id` and `customer_id`

I map through the `services` and create a `saleservice` with the `service_id` and the `sale_id` that I just created. But for some reason I get the error above.

Comment: Consider using Sequelize's built-in associations functions: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/